# How to have multiple OpenGL windows open on a single form in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I am having some difficulties having multiple instances of a volume renderer open on a single form using visual studio.

This is what my form looks like at the moment:

[image]

What I'm trying to do however, is have a split screen where instead of the single black box you have 4 windows on this same form.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just draw at different positions? or modify viewport? I dunno. I never tried having multiple OpenGL contexts.. I'd imagine on Windows you could have multiple DC's and call swap buffer on each one or setup a context on each one, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Why not simply create 4 controls instead of one, each with its own context?

Answer (score 0):

Use glViewport specify where to render within one window. You might want glScissor (with glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST)) too to prevent the rasterizer to render outside the specified viewport.